# Não seria uma boa idéia se pudessemos negativar os comentários?

Tags: debate, status-recusado, comentários, votos

Não seria uma boa idéia se pudessemos negativar os comentários?

Creio que eles também possam ser importantes para resposta, mas as vezes são ditas coisas que mais atrapalham do que ajudam!

Comment: Isso ai vai fazer a alegria dos maniacos de downvoters.

Comment: Os comentários ou prestam para alguma coisa, ou devem ser excluídos.

Comment: Eu andei limando um monte deles esses dias, os moderadores adoraram o trabalho que dei pra eles :D

Comment: @bigown, agora entendi o sumiço de um comentário meu. Como eu nem lembro do que se tratava, fez bem.

Comment: @bfavaretto Idealmente sim. Mas na prática a teoria nunca é igual à prática... Ou "jogo é jogo e treino é treino"... Ou alguma coisa assim

Comment: @Gabe Você é a favor de downvotes em comentários? Eu não sou absolutamente contra, mas acho desnecessário

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu tenho diversas ressalvas com sistemas de votos, em geral (até em perguntas e respostas), então minha primeira reação a essa pergunta é questionar a necessidade de ter sequer *upvotes* em comentários... Eu entendo que o downvote seria uma extensão natural e até útil, mas acho que causaria mais problemas do que soluções. No final das contas sou contra, mas não mais do que já sou desfavorável a upvotes  nos comentários.

Comment: @Gabe, seria possível explicar de forma sucinta sua bronca com upvotes em comentários?

Comment: @Dherik Acho que a explicação mais curta é que se comentários servem para ajudar a esclarecer o post, e comentários não relevantes (seja por serem ruins ou por terem sido resolvidos) devem ser removidos para evitar ruido, então não há porque estabelecer o concurso de popularidade por meio de votos. Se levarmos em consideração que os comentários não são ordenados por votos, fica ainda mais evidente que o voto não tem peso nenhum além de popularidade, e que muitos votos em um comentário não tem relevância alguma.

Comment: @Gabe discordo com a parte de ser contra upvotes. Os votos em comentários me ajudam muito na hora de encontrar os comentários mais relevantes ou avisos de perigos e erros numa resposta. Além disso, eles não alteram a reputação de qualquer jeito (pelo que eu me lembre, faz tempo que não recebo upvotes em comentários)

Comment: @Gabe, o "voto não tem peso nenhum" não é correto, servem para dar destaque quando só aparecem alguns de muitos comentários... ou mudou isso?

Comment: @brasofilo COntinua igual, mas como você mesmo disse, isso só acontece em casos em que há comentários suficientes pra justificar esconder alguns

Comment: Colaborando para a filosofia dos _upvotes_, eles também significam que outras pessoas concordam com aquilo, então em vez de outras pessoas comentarem "Eu também concordo com o que o _Fulano_ disse...", basta dar um _upvote_.

Comment: Considero muito útil o upvote em comentários. E acredito que não tem nada a ver com vaidade ou popularidade. Principalmente no SO em inglês em respostas mais antigas com muitos votos, os upvotes se sobressaem e muitas vezes corrigem ou complementam algo na resposta que é essencial para casos específicos. As vezes o autor da resposta até complementa baseado nos comentários, mas as vezes não, e principalmente no segundo caso eles são sim essenciais.

Comment: Que o _upvote_ não tem a ver com vaidade, discordo para alguns casos. Já vi gente recebendo +12 em comentários, sendo que o comentário não ajudou em nada com a pergunta :). Sem contar que até as piadas em comentários ganham +1

Comment: Acho que devemos analisar o padrão e não exceções. Exceções poderão  existir em todos os assuntos que tratarmos, mas no geral eu vejo como algo muito útil.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*"Não seria uma boa idéia se pudessemos negativar os comentários?"*

**Não, não seria.**

Do que eu entendo de Stack, é [basicamente isto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4245/n%C3%A3o-seria-uma-boa-idea-se-pudessemos-negativar-os-coment%C3%A1rios#comment12176_4245) que o bfavaretto diz:

> Os comentários ou prestam para alguma coisa, ou devem ser excluídos.

Sua função é meramente auxiliar para esclarecer alguma coisa da pergunta/resposta, orientar o autor, ou semelhante. Normalmente, se é um comentário útil/construtivo vai receber votos (positivos) que fazem que tenha destaque se existem muitos outros. Às vezes, tem comentários humorísticos/irônicos/sarcásticos, ou um simples parabéns, que também recebem vários votos.

Em qualquer caso, a "negativação" para comentários é esta (e o efeito desejado é eliminá-lo da face da terra):
[image]

Os comentários "engraçadinhos" caem na categoria "não construtivo". Muitas vezes o comentário é feito com arte e elegância e permanece vivo porque não machuca e alegra um pouco o dia.

Comment: Não sinalizem meu comentário...rsrsrs, mas as vezes acho importante parabenizar o autor da pergunta ou resposta, além é claro de dar o voto, que nesse caso expressou exatamente aquilo que eu penso sobre o assunto.

Comment: @SneepS Acrescentei outra categoria "votar por parabéns", jjjjjj

Comment: Votos de parabéns/obrigado costumam ser descartáveis. O que mostra que os votos não servem para muita coisa.

Comment: @bigown, além do destaque que comentei também serve pra ganhar uma medalhinha, e quem, neste Stack esquecido de deus, não quer mais uma medalhinha :P